# Windows Bat-file for Drag n Drop Imagefile for Imagemagick

Tags: drag-and-drop, batch-file, imagemagick, cmd

it s the first time i try this page. I ve just installed imagemagick on a windows 7 machine and the command "identify" is excactly what i ve been looking for.
I just want to do a bat file now, where i can drag a imagefile on it and then this command will be executed and a txt-file with the result will be saved.
I just cant handle it. What i ve got until now is:

```
set SOURCE=%1
identify -verbose %SOURCE%
```

But my Output is just a:

```
set SOURCE=-verbose
identify -verbose -verbose
```

So he is changing my Source-Variable? Why?
This seems to be so short and simple but i really got stucked now.
Maybe someone could give me a hint. Thx in advance

Comment: works on my machine and should so. just use %1 instead of the variable and insert a "echo %1" and a "pause" line to debug.

Comment: If `identify` is also the name of the batch file, it is likely that the script is calling itself. In that case, adding the appropriate extension (probably `.exe`) or, still better, the full path to the called executable's name should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this.

---

```
@echo off
set /p SOURCE=%1
echo.
echo Command: identify -verbose %SOURCE%
identify -verbose %SOURCE%
pause
```

---